# Gradle Maven Bom Properties

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm looking into migrating from maven to gradle and in our current setup we have a master pom that defines all of our version dependencies.

the project name is master-pom and has snippets like this:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-beanutils-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

....
and later down in the file we define something along these lines:

```
<properties>
    <commons-beanutils-version>1.9.1</commons-beanutils-version>
</properties>
```

Now, this is what I have so far:

```groovy
 plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "1.2.4"
    id "nebula.dependency-recommender" version "3.7.0"
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

apply plugin: 'nebula.dependency-recommender'
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"




version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility =  '1.8'

description = """best-service-ever"""



repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       maven { url 'https://repo.server.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
          credentials {
               username 'username'
               password nexusPassword
          }
    }
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()


}

dependencyRecommendations {
   mavenBom module: 'biz.company.name:master-pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}



dependencies {
          ... some dependencies
          compile 'biz.company.name:db-schema'
}
```

At this point it'll pick up the version named ${db-version} and use the correctly defined one from the build-maven.  The problem is, I need to override that version with a specific version.

I tried putting the value in gradle.properties, but there's an issue with that.

db-version is unsupported by gradle, since it interprets - as arithmetic operation.  I instead tried defining the value as

db_version=0.0.1700

which seems to work, but how do I set it so it overrides the $db-version value.  I would like to avoid having to explicitly set the version: in every artifact.

My ideal scenario would either allow me to simply override the properties that come from the bom file.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Or have a work around?

Comment: Do you mean BOM or POM?

Comment: Gradle seems to call this pattern bom, but it's basically a maven pom file published to manage dependencies.  to quote:  https://gradle.org/migrating-a-maven-build-to-gradle/.  """Maven allows you specify a list of dependencies in a separate POM inside tags. This special type of POM (a BOM) can then be imported into other POMs so that you have consistent library names and versions across all your projects."""

Comment: I did find this pattern that seems to work though it's a bit brittle imo.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a partial answer.

I did find this pattern that seems to work though it's a bit brittle and a bit too verbose.  What I really would like to do is say.

```
${common-service-version} = MyVersionNumber  (which is defined in gradle.properties)
```

Example Fix:

```
dependencyRecommendations {
   mavenBom module: 'biz.company.name:master-pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
   /* Override properties from mavenBom */
   map recommendations: [ 'biz.company.name:shared-common-service': services_common_global_version,
    'biz.company.name:services-core': services_common_global_version,
    'biz.neustar.ms:test-services-common': services_common_global_version,
    'biz.company.name:mip-db-schema':  db_version,
    'biz.company.name:services-api': services_api_version
   ]
}
```

This does work though you have to re-define the dependencies in a way.  If someone has a better pattern let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Found the idea here: https://dzone.com/articles/specifying-gradle-build, adapted a little in order to make it work on the my current version of gradle (not sure if that was the problem, but anyway…)

Specifying common version in gradle comes down to basically two simple steps:

1. Create a file `gradle.properties` if it doesn't exists yet. Here arbitrary configuration may be stored, e.g. `jackson.version = 2.10.0` (please, **do not** copy it, always check for actual fresh versions on maven central or alike).
2. Use defined properties via `project.properties` map inside double-quoted template string which specifies dependency. For example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${project.properties['jackson.version']}"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${project.properties['jackson.version']}"
    //...
}
```

Of course, alternative syntax can be used insted:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-core", version: project.properties['jackson.version'])
    implementation group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name: "jackson-databind", version: project.properties['jackson.version']
    //...
}
```