# Using maven property in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a `build.grade` that references a pom/bom file.

I am using gradle 4.6, so I specified `enableFeaturePreview("IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT")` in my `settings.gradle`.

The bom file contains the `dependencyManagement` tag and that all works fine.  I can add gradle dependencies for a library mentioned in the `dependencyManagement` tag without specifying the version and gradle will get it from the bom.

Now, I want to use a library that is not in the bom's `dependencyManagement` tag but is in the same family as one that is.  Specifically, sl4fj-api is defined in the bom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${version.lib.slf4j}</version>
</dependency>
```

and I want to use the slf4j-ext library with the same version:

```
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-ext"
```

Is the above somehow possible?

I suspect not, but this seems like it should be doable:

```
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:${version.lib.slf4j}"
```

But alas, the bom properties are not accessible using project::getProperty: `Could not get unknown property 'version.lib.slf4j'`

Or, given the `slf4j-api` dependency, can I get its version number after it has been evaluated and add another dependency using that version number or is that an ordering dilemma?

Any suggestions?

I found the following related question:

[Gradle Maven Bom Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205560/gradle-maven-bom-properties)

But I really do not want to do a full blown parse of the bom inside every sub-project.

I also found the following 'partial answer':

[How to get properties of parent Maven to Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148869/how-to-get-properties-of-parent-maven-to-gradle)

but here it seems like the dependency information, including the version, is being duplicated from the bom/pom instead of referenced.